# Is it still possible to configure a vm queue as persistent in Mule 3.4.X?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to configure a vm connector like so:

```
<vm:connector name="recordDeletedActivityDLQStore">
   <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="500" >
     <file-queue-store/>
   </vm:queue-profile>
</vm:connector>
```

Mule Studio complains that  is not a permitted child element of vm:queue-profile.  This will not build and run either.  I've tried other possible inputs for defining the nature of the queue store without any luck.  I can't find any documentation on how to configure persistent vm queues that works.  Specifically, I have tried adding the attribute persistent="true" to the queue-profile element as described in VM Transport Reference:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/VM+Transport+Reference

This doesn't seem to be supported anymore either...

Is it still possible to configure a vm queue as persistent in Mule 3.4.X?

Comment: are you using clustering?

Comment: No, Nikos, I'm not currently using clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct and works: you can see that messages are persisted on disk under `.mule/${app_name}/queuestore/${queue_name}/`.

Persistence only occurs for `one-way` VM queues, not `request-response` ones. For the latter, no queueing occurs whatsoever.

Also, disregard Studio complaints about your configuration not being valid. Mule has the final word on configuration validity, and yours is just fine.