# Can anyone share knowledge on jms queue vs vm queue. where vm queue persist messages?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Can anyone share knowledge on jms queue vs vm queue. where vm queue persist messages. Please share with any understandable example

vm queue vs jms queue.. am using activemq message broker for jms implementation. I want to know the difference between jms queue and vmqueue.

Comment: Copy/pasting the same content over and over is not useful or meaningful, especially when that content is vague and broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM is an in memory, only support queues, non persistent

JMS, separate message broker, support queues and topics, can be persisted

So for VM when you Mule instance goes down messages that were still in that in memory queue would be lost.

This link from the docs gives you even more info:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.7/reliability-patterns#comparing-endpoints-in-reliability-patterns

Comment: Mule allows persistent queue mechanisms (File, in-memory,default etc). We dont lose messages when persistent queues are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Mule's VM **by default** persist messages in **in-memory queue**. That's the reason the message gets lost for the messages that are not proceed when server goes down.
You can configure VM to persist message **on disk**. Something like the following :-

```
<vm:connector name="SaveToDisc" doc:name="VM">
   <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="500" >
     <file-queue-store/>
   </vm:queue-profile>
</vm:connector>
```

**Please Note:** VM file persistency will not work on cluster env.
reference :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/vm-transport-reference
On the other hand JMS are external to Mule and use message broker, so it doesn't effect if Mule server goes down as the unprocessed can be still accessible when Mule serve comes up.

For more comparison, you can check the following article :- https://www.ricston.com/blog/vm-jms/

Comment: thanks.. here my doubt is if i use queue store is <file-queue-store>, where the messages are stored i mean which in location that file is created.. for example if i use default-persistent-queue-store then its created the queuestore folder in .mule folder in workspace.. what about file-que-store??

Comment: more over, its says the. file-queue-store
DEPRECATED: file-queue-store is deprecated since Mule 3.5 and will be removed in Mule 4.0. Use default-
 persistent-queue-store instead. A simple file-based queue store.

Comment: If you configure `<file-queue-store>`, the file will be created in `.mule\.mule\{YourApplicationName}\queuestore` in your workspace ... Also check this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807395/is-it-still-possible-to-configure-a-vm-queue-as-persistent-in-mule-3-4-x